# Allow close votes even if a question is already closed

Tags: discussion, feature-request, vote-to-close, closed-questions, vote-to-reopen

Just an idea.

How about allowing casting close votes on questions that have already been closed?

This would

- Allow the system to show how bad the community thinks a question is. For instance, a question with 100 close votes on it could be a bigger candidate for deletion than one with only the five, which may still be salvageable.
- Allow me to counteract the reopen votes. If I encounter a closed question that has reopen votes on it, but I'm sure I want to keep it closed, I shouldn't have to wait until it is actually reopened before I could cast my close vote.

Thoughts?

Comment: But one edit can make a world of difference, making it a great question (New user that didn't bother to read the help center, and then got a link in the comments, and took actions to improve their question)

Comment: If it is gathering 100 close votes, in all honesty enough 20k+ users would have probably deleted it by that point. Not to mention the flagging mechanism (very low quality) which upon being marked helpful deletes the post regardless of closure.

Comment: For "shouldn't have to wait until it is actually reopened before I could cast my close vote" would you also agree with the reverse? "shouldn't have to wait until it is actually closed before I could cast my reopen vote"

Comment: Don't we already have problems because not everything gets closed? If we do this, won't ppl just run out of close votes on questions already closed instead of moving on to opened questions that also deserve closure?

Comment: @Patrice Well, I personally don't run out of close votes every day. Maybe I'm doing it wrong...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't think this would work. Mainly:

**A bad question can be edited into a good one**, at which point the close votes should not be counted. It would be unfair to keep it closed just because it used to be bad.

In addition, it is a waste *a lot* of a close votes on a small number of "popular" questions. There are currently [over 9000 questions in the Close Vote queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close) - close one of them instead.
Also, UI-wise - what is the meaning of voting to close on an already closed question?

We already have a similar mechanism - you can down-vote a bad question to indicate it is bad, which leads to [easier deletion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/7586) of the post, and hides it from the main page.

Comment: I already covered your main point by mentioning that a question with only 5 close votes has a greater probability of being salvaged (with an edit) than one with 100 close votes. You do have another point though: the downvotes. Closed questions can still be (and often are) downvoted, to indicate that people agree it's indeed low quality. So, OK. I'll wait a while to see if other answers come up though.

Comment: Oh well, seeing the distribution of votes to this question and its answer, let's put it out of its misery.